# In a ModelForm/Form collect the information for another Model connected thru a ManyToMany Relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have 3 models Account, Email and Item.

An Account can have multiple Email and and Item can multiple Email and an Email can have multiple Item.

```
class Account(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class AccountEmail(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Item(models.Model):
   emails = models.ManyToManyField(AccountEmail, related_name='account_emails_products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

The emails can be added at the Item level, none or multiple(dynamic no fixed number).

```
<input type="email" id="email" size="30" >
<input type="email" id="email" size="30" >
<input type="email" id="email" size="30" >
```

The form:

```
class ItemModelForm(forms.ModelForm)
  class Meta:
    model = Product
```

My issues is how do I add this to form and save it.

I need visually to appear as input forms, gather the values, validate and check for all inputs, save them in AccountEmails and after create relations.

Being M2M (dynamic) I can represent them in the ModelForm, but use a collector field, or not.

How do I gather the info to the cleaning/validation if the fields don't exist in reality ?

Comment: @waranlogesh I don't see how django filters can help, my issues is not related to filtering, but add dynamic fields and gather info that is not present in the model

Comment: What do you mean with "If the fields don't exist in reality"? Can't you just have two separate ModelForms? One for the account, and one for the emails?

Comment: The emails are added dynamic when I submit  the Item form. By 'don't exist in reality' I mean there are not an implicit part of the Item form. Also being a M2M connection and not an FK, if I try to show the field will be as an array of integers. Instead I need text inputs.